# How to get fastreport memo value

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, fastreport

I have a hard time getting memo value from fastreport to delphi. I have a memo in fastreport with computed value and i want to get this value and send it to my delphi edit text.

I tried this code but the result is only text not a value

`txtValue.text := TfrxMemoView(frxReport1.FindComponent('Memo3')).Text;`

Comment: I dont understand. It's a memo. These contain text. If you want to put the result inside in a TEdit that's exactly what you need, isn't it?

Comment: my memo text is computed [memo1.value + memo2.value]

Comment: Please show simple examples of `Memo1.Value`, `Memo2.Value` and what you expect the computed value to be and how actual value deviates from the expected.

Comment: @UliGerhardt The `TfrxMemoView` component has two properties `Text` and `Value`, the OP mention in his question the `Value` property, and it seems he can access the `Text` and don't know how to access the `Value` property.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as

```
begin
    // Get Text property 
    txtValue.text := TfrxMemoView(frxReport1.FindComponent('Memo3')).Text;
    // Get Value property
    txtValue.text := TfrxMemoView(frxReport1.FindComponent('Memo3')).Value;
end;
```

If you want to concatenate two strings from `Text` and `Value` properties then

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    // Set the Text property
    TfrxMemoView(frxReport1.FindObject('Memo3')).Text:= 'MyFirstString';
    // Set the Value property
    TfrxMemoView(frxReport1.FindObject('Memo3')).Value:= 'MySecondString';
    // Concatenate the strings and assign the result to the TEdit.Text property
    txtValue.Text:= Concat(TfrxMemoView(frxReport1.FindObject('Memo3')).Text,
                           ' ',
                           TfrxMemoView(frxReport1.FindObject('Memo3')).Value
                          );
end;
```

Comment: **Please** use temp variables, at least in the `Concat` line.